# how to reduce loading time of php script

Tags: php

I am taking lat, lng from mysql and load the map. But in this iteration 1000's of data loading for drawing route on map but for this process it takes too long time.
After loading the code it takes 30 sec and above so please help me how to reduce the loading time of this script
Thanks

```
<?php
    $result=mysql_query("select * from marker1 where  date='$maxdate' and time BETWEEN '$mintime' AND '$maxtime' and imei_no='$vehicle_imei_no1'")or die(mysql_error());

    $markers =new SimpleXMLElement('<markers/>');//Create SimpleXMLElement object
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ //Add each column value a node of the XML object
    $marker = $markers->addChild('marker');
    $marker->addChild('lat',$row['lat']);
    $marker->addChild('lng',$row['lng']);
    $marker->addChild('date',$row['date']);
    $marker->addChild('time',$row['time']);
    $marker->addChild('speed',$row['speed']);
    $marker->addChild('vehicle_status',$row['vehicle_status']);

    array_push($lat_lng,$row['lat'],$row['lng']);

    if($row['vehicle_status']=='M' && $row['speed'] >3){
    array_push($allTime,$row['time']);
    }else {
    array_push($allTime,-1);
    }

    if($row['vehicle_status']=='M' && $row['speed'] <= 3 ){
    array_push($parkedTime,$row['time']);
    }else {
    array_push($parkedTime,-1);
    }

    }

      $fp=fopen('genxml.xml','wb'); //Create the XML file
      fwrite($fp,$markers->asXML());      //Write the XML nodes
      fclose($fp);  
    include 'currentlocation1.php';

    ?>
```

Comment: You have to post your code inside the question , for us to help your with your query or code problems , we cannot immagine about how your code would be.

Comment: Maybe it is not the loading of the data that takes that much time, but the rendering of that many points by the client system. PHP can easily load big amounts of data within short time. We have script which has to load about 6 GiB of data from the database on each run, but the loading process runs about 60-90 seconds, so some "1000's of data" should not pose a problem.

Comment: I'm going to assume your refering to a route made up of 1000's of points, in which case it sounds like the issue isn't relating to PHP but more JavaScript in rendering the route on the map. Total assumption though as you've posted no code.

Comment: Have you tried to log time used to see that this actually is where the time is spent? Try to log time used from start of the file to where you begin writing the file